# Какой аналог itemOperations в api-platform 3 версии?

Tags: php, api, symfony, php8, api-platform.com

Ситуация в следующем. Обновил `api-platform/core` до последней 3 версии и не могу исправить аннотацию (версии 2) на атрибуты (версии 3).

Вот аннотация для второй версии:

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *       "get"={
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"="order:list"}
 *       },
 *       "post"={
 *          "security"="is_granted('ROLE_USER')",
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"="order:list:write"}
 *       }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *       "get"={
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"="order:item"}
 *       },
 *     },
 * )
 */
```

Почитав доку для третьей версии, частично перевел аннотацию на атрибуты, получилось:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(
            normalizationContext: ['groups' => 'order:list']
        ),
        new Post(
            normalizationContext: ['groups' => 'order:list:write'],
            security: ["is_granted('ROLE_USER')"]
        )
    ],
)]
```

Но вот как перевести вот этот участок:

```php
 *     itemOperations={
 *       "get"={
 *          "normalization_context"={"groups"="order:item"}
 *       },
 *     },
```

Ума не приложу :( Кто сталкивался с подобным вопросом? Подскажите.